# Does "The loved are happy." make sense?

Tags: grammar

Could I replace "The loved ones are happy." with " The loved are happy."
Is it possible to replace?

I learned that 'the' plus 'adjective' means 'prural normal noun'.
I think that Past participal 'loved' is a adjective.
Is it right?

Comment: Yes. Please look around for usage examples. You will find some good ones.

Comment: The quick and the dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Collective Adjectives](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adjectives.htm):
>
> When the definite article, the, is combined with an adjective describing a class or group of people, the resulting phrase can act as a noun: the poor, the rich, the oppressed, the homeless, the lonely, the unlettered, the unwashed, the gathered, the dear departed. The difference between a Collective Noun (which is usually regarded as singular but which can be plural in certain contexts) and a collective adjective is that the latter is always plural and requires a plural verb:
>
> - The rural poor have been ignored by the media.
> - The rich of Connecticut are responsible.
> - The elderly are beginning to demand their rights.
> - The young at heart are always a joy to be around.

In your examples, the loved,  refers to all the people who are loved, and the sentence technically works.

(grammar.ccc.commnet.edu)

Comment: +1. But is that from http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adjectives.htm. ? Maybe you forgot to cite.

Comment: There are nominal adjectives that are not collectives: _The opposite is often the case_ / _The good is the enemy of the best_ / _The greatest of these is love_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  -  ..and as such, they that a singular verb.

Comment: Is it not the norm only in British English to assign plural verbs to a collective noun. "The team are playing well", "The family are in desperate trouble", I have a few American and Canadian friends, whom I've never seen using a plural verb for collective noun, they always go for the singular verb. Can anyone explain why plural verbs are almost rejected for collective nouns in Americas?

Comment: @Andy The difference is real, the "American" way seems more logical to me (well, being American): When the group is conceptualized as a unit, it's treated as singular: The family lives in the green house. When conceptualized as multiple individuals, it's plural: The family travel from all over the country to gather for their annual reunion. Sometimes an example doesn't categorize neatly one way or the other.